# Why is that the nmos and pmos in parallel "compensate each other"?

Tags: nmos, pmos

Why is that the nmos and pmos in parallel "compensate each other"?
I use the simulation and found both current through nmos and pmos goes up if voltage across drain and source goes up.
[image]

Comment: The resistance of a FET channel is not independent of U(ds) as it is compared to a resistor. This circuit seems to need a linear resistance here, I can only guess that the linearity errors of P and N channel in parallel are less significant in this application.

Comment: looks like BS to me as  both FETS are on or off and both pull up to V+ with Rt so Vout = Vdd at all times

Comment: This design lacks details on Vt, gm and Vin, Vout.  I say it won't work as described poorly.  this is what I would do to make an active R Terminator near Vdd/2  https://tinyurl.com/27jplsag